# How to iterate over an array and display duplicate elements after?

Tags: javascript

I have a table where the first column is an array of elements, for example

```
[apple, banana, cherry, grapes, apple]
```

And with the adjacent column, if the element is repeated, it should display on which line the repetition is taking place

| id | fruits | dublicate with |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | apple | 5 |
| 2 | banana |  |
| 3 | cherry |  |
| 4 | grapes |  |
| 5 | apple | 1 |
| 6 | apple |  |

How can this be properly implemented?

I tried a solution like this, but then it shows not the first value found

```
let elems = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grapes', 'apple', 'apple'];


    elems.forEach(function (value, index, arr){

        let first_index = arr.indexOf(value);
        let last_index = arr.lastIndexOf(value);

         if(first_index !== last_index){

         console.log('Dublicate value: ' + value + ', ' + 'Index: ' + arr.indexOf(value) + ' and ' + arr.lastIndexOf(value) );

         }

    });
```

Comment: what if you have three of the same? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz Added the code above. Should output the first value found

Comment: What is the expected ouput?

Comment: @iota "Dublicate values: apple, Index: 0 and 4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first use `filter` to find the duplicates, then loop for the indexes of each occurrence.

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grapes', 'apple'];
const duplicates = arr.filter((x, i) => arr.indexOf(x) !== i);
for (const x of duplicates) {
  console.log(`Duplicate value ${x} at indexes ${
    [...Array(arr.length).keys()].filter(i => arr[i] === x)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I created this which will generate you the output of every value with their corresponding indices which would make it easy to display them even when there are multiple occurences.

I hope you understand how the reduce and the forEach work, those are important functions in JavaScript you should mabe reas up on :)

```js
let arr = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grapes', 'apple'];
let arrindexed = arr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    let indices = [];
    arr.forEach((val, ind) => {
        if(ind !== index && val === curr) indices.push(ind + 1);
    });
    acc.push([curr, indices]);

    return acc;
}, [])

console.log(arrindexed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code for iterating through the table and logging the duplicate column index.

```js
  var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
  var fruits = [];
  var duplicatelabelcols = [];
     //iterate through rows
  for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      var row = table.rows[i];
       //iterate through columns

     //check if not 1st row
     if (i !== 0) {
       for (var j = 0; j < row.cells.length; j++) {
          var col = row.cells[j];
          //if 2nd column
          if (j === 1) {
            //check if fruit inside fruit array
            if(fruits.includes(row.cells[j].innerHTML)) {
              duplicatelabelcols.push(fruits.indexOf(row.cells[j].innerHTML));
              duplicatelabelcols.push(i-1);
            }

            //add fruit to fruits array
            fruits.push(row.cells[j].innerHTML);
          }
       }
    }  
  }

  console.log(duplicatelabelcols);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Fruits</th>
    <th>dup with</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>cherry</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>grapes</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>apple</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a single loop with a closure over an object which keeps the references to all rows with same item.

```js
const
    items = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'grapes', 'apple', 'apple'],
    table = items.map((hash => (v, index) => {
        const temp = { index, row: [index + 1, v] };
        (hash[v] ??= []).push(temp);

        if (hash[v].length === 2) {
            hash[v][0].row[2] = hash[v][1].index + 1;
            hash[v][1].row[2] = hash[v][0].index + 1;
        }

        return temp.row;
    })({}))

table.map(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)));
```